# Insert to MySql Database in loop without deadlock

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await, transactions, deadlock

im using nodejs (AdonisJs) to create a script to update my database (Mysql). Something like this:

```
const trx = await Database.beginTransaction();
try {
    const async = use('async');

    await async.eachOfLimit(arr, 50, async item => {
        `select * from table1 where id = 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE`
        `insert into ....`
        `another query...`
    });
    trx.commit();
} catch (err) {
    trx.rollback();
}
```

Problem is `eachOfLimit` running query in parallel, so code above throw error: `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`. If i run it with `for of` synchronous loop, it working fine.
How to fix this or any idea for my script. Sorry for my bad english.

Btw i using `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` or `FOR UPDATE` to avoid duplicate when many query `INSERT` run even though i used `findOrCreate` to check if row existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution: use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `INSERT`.
So i remove the `SELECT` query and use `INSERT IGNORE`.

```
const language = await Database.raw(trx('languages').insert({
      ...languageItem,
      created_at: this.getTimeNow(),
      updated_at: this.getTimeNow()
}).toString().replace('insert', 'INSERT IGNORE'));
```

And my script run without deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using "FOR UPDATE" instead of "LOCK IN SHARE MODE" to prevent locks on the same rows.

From [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE

Sets a shared mode lock on any rows that are read. Other sessions can read the rows, but cannot modify them until your transaction commits. If any of these rows were changed by another transaction that has not yet committed, your query waits until that transaction ends and then uses the latest values.

SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

For index records the search encounters, locks the rows and any associated index entries, the same as if you issued an UPDATE statement for those rows. Other transactions are blocked from updating those rows, from doing SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE, or from reading the data in certain transaction isolation levels. Consistent reads ignore any locks set on the records that exist in the read view. (Old versions of a record cannot be locked; they are reconstructed by applying undo logs on an in-memory copy of the record.)

Comment: I try `FOR UPDATE` already, still same error. I think problem here is `eachOfLimit` run many query `SELECT` at the same time, so they lock the same row.